How to configure or ignore Kibana 8's Elastic enrollment token running on Docker for .Net 8 Logging
PROBLEM STATEMENT
I have added Kibana and Elasticsearch 8.7.1 for logging on a couple .Net 8 projects.  Here is one proof of concept implementation
The problem I am having is, sometimes when I go to the default Kibana url, I get asked to enter an enrollment token... but not every time!  Also, I have no idea how to find an enrollment token or how to "configure manually."
PATH A : Search for an enrollment token.
Kibana home page at http://localhost:5601/ says:

The enrollment token is automatically generated when you start Elasticsearch for the first time. You might need to scroll back a bit in the terminal to view it.


I am creating these two docker containers from one compose file, and executing via command line with docker compose up however there is no mention of token or enrollment in the terminal or the docker containers' logs.


To generate a new enrollment token, run the following command from the Elasticsearch installation directory: bin\elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token.bat --scope kibana


In order to attempt this, I am:


Opening Docker for Windows.
Clicking on the name of my Elasticsearch container.
Clicking on the Exec tab.
Pasting that command in.
Negative Result: sh: binelasticsearch-create-enrollment-token.bat: command not found
Also attempted modifying the command: elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token --scope kibana
Negative Result: ERROR: [xpack.security.enrollment.enabled] must be set to true to create an enrollment token

PATH B: Configure Manually (search for an ip address)
Kibana home page at http://localhost:5601/ has a button labelled Configure Manually expecting an address (presumably of the Elasticsearch container).  The default value is https://localhost:9200, which I can hit from my browser to confirm Elasticsearch is running.  This does not work here.
I believe the reason Kibana can't access this url, is because it is inside the same container, on the same network as Elasticsearch.  I expect there should be an ip address where localhost appears in the url.  These are the steps I have taken:

In Docker for Windows, click on Kibana's Container name.
Click Inspect tab.
Observe addresses in

"Networks":{
  "zz-xxx_elasticnetwork":{
    "Gateway":"172.20.0.1",
    "IPAddress":"172.20.0.3",
    // ...abbreviated code

Example trials on Kibana hompage:
https://172.20.0.1:9200
https://172.20.0.3:9200
Neither of these ip addresses work to get the Kibana home page to connect to the cluster.
If I change Https to Http, then a whole different verification code is requested.
SUMMARY
So, question is... how do I get this dependably working for a local dev environment without a bunch of hoops to jump through?  I've seen it work before!  I'm not intentionally turning on any security features, I just want to do my "code monkey" thing and make stuff work, then eventually hand it off to DevOps to wire up the secure connections.  The most frustrating thing is... sometimes it DOES NOT ask me for this enrollment token to get into the kibana page!
CODE FOR REVIEW
For further transparency... this is what I am spinning up my containers with:
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=zz-xxx
ELK_STACK_VERSION=8.13.2
ES_PORT=9200
KIBANA_PORT=5601

networks:
  elasticnetwork:
    driver: bridge

services:

  zz-elasticsearch:
    container_name: zz-elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${ELK_STACK_VERSION}
    networks:      
      - elasticnetwork
    ports:
      - ${ES_PORT}:9200
    volumes:
      - zz-els01-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.watcher.enabled=false
      - xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
  
  zz-kibana:
    container_name: zz-kibana
    networks:      
      - elasticnetwork
    depends_on:
      - zz-elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${ELK_STACK_VERSION}
    ports:
      - ${KIBANA_PORT}:5601
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://localhost:9200 

volumes:
  zz-els01-data:
  

I hope the thoroughness I have explained this in will help other folks get running with local dev easier!  Thanks all, and I appreciate you getting this far

I also faced this issue when trying to setup a local development environment with elasticsearch 8 and kibana using a docker-compose.yml file.
I got it working by changing http://localhost:9200 to http://172.17.0.1:9200. I'm using a Linux host, so this post explains why that IP address has to be used.
For Windows and Mac, you should be able to use host.docker.internal
